# Using symbols in an input to format text

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I'm struggling to find a solution which allows a user to input in a input field, however they can style their text when it displays after the input for was submitted.

For example, a user could enter `**message**` into the input field, JavaScript can detect that the `**` on the start of the word/sentence and make this text **bold**. Essentially StackOverflow does this shown in the image below:

[image: Stackoverflow example of styling input]

However my code works, but barely. For instance, the user can input their text, and format it in the input with symbols types such as:

- `**` = **Bold**
- `*` = *Italics*
- `__` = Underlined, etc

Below is my attempt:

```js
    if (msg.includes('**')) {
        msg = msg.replace("**", "");
        msg = msg.replace("**", "");
        msg = `<b>${msg}</b>`
    }
    if (msg.includes('__')) {
        msg = msg.replace("__", "");
        msg = msg.replace("__", "");
        msg = `<u>${msg}</u>`
    }
```

However this code would not work and mean a user could just enter `**message` instead of using it on `point a` to `point b` of the text they want to style.

Also, this code would make the whole text the format anyway, I just would like only the text within the formatted symbols. Could anyone please provide a solution?

**TL;DR**

Simply a user can input their text into an input field, however they may want to format it, let's say **bold**, the user within the input can have their text:

User text: `This is a **desired** example`

Display on page as: This is a **desired** example

However, my currently non-functioning code applies the format to the whole text instead of the selected within the symbols:

User text: `This is a **bad** example`

Display on page as: **This is a bad example**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

````js
let msg = "This is a **desired** *```example```*"
msg = msg
  .replace(/\*{2}([\w\W]*?)\*{2}/g, '<b>$1</b>')
  .replace(/`{3}([\w\W]*?)`{3}/g, '<code>$1</code>')
  .replace(/\*([\w\W]*?)\*/g, '<u>$1</u>')

document.body.innerHTML = msg
````

*Details*:

- `.replace(/\*{2}([\w\W]*?)\*{2}/g, '<b>$1</b>')` - wraps the strings between `**` and `**` with bold tags
- `.replace(/`{3}([\w\W]*?)`{3}/g, '<code>$1</code>')` - wraps strings between triple backticks with `<code>` tag
- `.replace(/\*([\w\W]*?)\*/g, '<u>$1</u>')` - wraps texts between single `*` with underline tags.